# Merging two NSArray removing duplicates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of Cities and an array of Countries.
These two objects have a property in common: the city name.
I need to create a new array adding all the Countries that have a city name not there in the Cities array.

I tried iterating on both arrays, comparing the city name and adding only the different one to the new array. The result is that, while it checks the first city, all the cities that have another name are added to the array and so also the other cities in the Cities array are already there.

```
self.filteredCountriesArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (Country* country in self.countries) {
    for (City *city in self.cities) {
        if (![country.city isEqualToString:city.name]) {
            [self.filteredCountriesArray addObject:country];
        }
    }
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: So you'll end up with a heterogeneous array of `City` and `Country` objects?  Is that desirable, as it sounds like you are going down the wrong path here.

Comment: Nope, not hererogeneous. The final array will contain only countries, but only the ones that does not contain the same city name I have in the Cities array.

Comment: Well `addObject:country` is wrong then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure whether I understand what you want, my guess is that you'd like to do something like this:

```
for (Country *country in self.countries) {
    BOOL found = NO;

    for (City *city in self.cities) {
        if ([country.city isEqualToString:city.name]) {
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        [self.filteredCountriesArray addObject:country];
    }
}
```

To speed that up, I'd create a `NSSet` with the city names first:

```
NSMutableSet *cityNames = [NSMutableSet set];
for (City *city in self.cities) {
    [cityNames addObject:city.name];
}

for (Country *country in self.countries) {
    if (![cityNames containsObject:county.city]) {
        [self.filteredCountriesArray addObject:country];
    }
}
```